# Ubuntu netstat command - howto keep it updating?

Tags: ubuntu, netstat

I know there is a way to run a netstat command on ubuntu so that it keeps updating.  Does anyone know?  I would like to know when a process opens or closes a socket:

```
sudo netstat -lnp |grep 12239
```

Comment: you should ask this on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap any command in `watch`, eg try

```
 watch -n 60 "sudo netstat | head 10"
```

where you could use your `grep` expression instead of `head 10`.  This now updates every 60 seconds, see `man watch`.